# Firebase Auth Error while using project on different device - unknown status code: 17499

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I and my colleagues keep running into this error again and again.
The console looks something like this:

[image]

Having 3 different people working on a single Android project.

After downloading the JSON file and pasting it in the appropriate location. App directory in Android project.

Now, as soon the app starts and asks for authentication, phone authentication is in my case. The following error is thrown in LOGCAT.

```
E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Requests from this Android client application ____package name_____ are blocked.
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests from this Android client application ___package name_____ are blocked. ]
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzti.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzud.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:3)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

The Authentication works perfectly fine on the first device I was using but if I add any further Sha-1 or Sha-256 to the console, it throws an error.

Comment: Please edit the question to list out the steps you're taking in the console and on your devices that you believe should prevent this error from happening.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the instructions you provide. Be specific - you might be doing something wrong.  Screenshots might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for helping @DougStevenson, I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found the solution to my problem.
The error clearly says "SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Requests from this Android client application ****package name****_ are blocked."

The problem was basically that there are 3 different persons working on the project, and each person would be assigned a separate `oauth_client` `cliend_id`. Now if we download JSON files directly from firebase, there are a few issues. It should look something like this:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "______",
    "firebase_url": "_______",
    "project_id": "______",
    "storage_bucket": "_______"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "mobile_project_id",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "________"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "client_id_0",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "______",
            "certificate_hash": "______"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "client_id_4",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "api_key_0"
        },
        {
          "current_key": "api_key_1"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "some_client_id",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Now, as you can see in oauth_client there are 2 clients, if I remove `client_id_4` data, it wouldn't matter much since my client id data is in `client_id_0` and the android app would work perfectly fine.

Downloading JSON file and using it directly works well only when you have 1 app and 1 person working on it but if there are many different devices and many different persons working on the project, you need to take matters into your hands.

The solution to the problem is:

1. If you have API Keys assigned specifically for a project check if it's correct or not. (ex. `api_key_0` is right and `api_key_1` is not of this project, so you need to remove api_key_1).
2. In the `oauth_client` keep only one `client_id`, specifically which belongs to you else it will throw the same error as I was getting.
3. For those wondering where to find `oauth_client` `client_id` [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and navigate to the section where it says "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs". Search for the one related to yours.
4. And finally, make changes appropriately.

The problem was because Firebase was reading wrong `client_id` from the JSON file even if the correct one was mentioned.